# Installing pip for two python versions (2.7 and 3.7) Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

Eylo stackers,

I have pip installed successfully in python 3.7, however can't seem to install it for python 2.7.

I have tried doing this through downloading get-pip.py and running cmd in the directory where it is installed through

- Shift clicking then 'Open command window'
- `python get-pip.py`
- It then proceeds to update pip... Which provides with this

  `Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.1
  Uninstalling pip-18.1:
    Successfully uninstalled pip-18.1
  Successfully installed pip-18.1`

I also tried 
`py -2 get-pip.py` (which presented me with this error)

```
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pip`
```

I'm trying to run an ancient python 2.7 script, and to do so I need to install pyHook and other libraries.

Which is difficult because i can't seem to find a way to install pip to python 2.7.

There was no solutions for windows, only MAC..

I've been browsing stack for over 3 hours for solutions, so for the love of God don't tell me this has already been answered.

**ERROR FROM** 
Inside the directory of where get-pip.py is stored (sc, won't post code)

https://gyazo.com/f66252aed6abb3ee42a86e84440866bd

And yes, i'm in the right directory

This is what i tried:

`C:\Python27\python -m pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

This is the error.

```
pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
platform.
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Callum\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: So you have both Python 2.7 and 3.7 installed? Are they both set in the environment variables? What happens when you call `python` vs `python2`?

Comment: python, comes up with 'Python 3.7.1' (loads python) and python2 is not recognised as an internal or external command.... What does setting them as environmental variables actually do, I have a Variable named 'Path' under the value 'C:\Python27' and 'pip' under 'C:\Python27\Scripts'.... But no path for Python3.7

Comment: Try running `C:\Python27\python` and if that succeeds in starting python 2.7 then run `C:\Python27\python get-pip.py` inside the folder where `get-pip.py` is. That should do it, I think.

Comment: Didn't seem to work, https://gyazo.com/f66252aed6abb3ee42a86e84440866bd

Comment: Two things: 1) try running PowerShell in admin mode and repeat. 2) What version of Python 2.7 do you have (`C:\Python27\python --version`)?

Comment: I have 'python 2.7.150' 64 bit...... And the powershell in administrator provided me with the same error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have **Python 2.7.9+** installed, you already have pip, so you can install packages with:

```
C:\Python27\python -m pip install <package-name>
```

To run the *script.py*:

```
C:\Python27\python script.py
```

Comment: I'll install Python 2.7.9 and see if it resolves the issue. :)

Comment: How about `C:\Python27\python -m ensurepip`?

Comment: Trying to install pyHook now that pip is clearly installed for my Python 2.7 version now.. I'm granted with the error above, in main post

Comment: Are you on 32bit or 64bit Windows?

Comment: 64 bit! Which is strange why I'm getting an error because the .whl file is correct..

Comment: Where did you download your wheel file from? [Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)?

Comment: Yes, I guess i can try redownloading it. But yes that's the same website.

Comment: Same error. It's so strange isn't it? Appreciate your help

Comment: I was having issues on MacOS. I found using the `python2.7 -m ensurepip` command then allowed me to use the `python -m pip install <package-name>` command. I had to prefix all of them with `sudo -H`.